# tracking issue on page not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, php-5.3

In my .htacess rule i have rule like

```
ErrorDocument 404 randomsite.com/404page.php
```

In my 404page.php, i m not able track the page from which i got 404 page.

Example:

If i click link "randomsite.com/notexists" its redirecting to my 404page.php but when i print_r($_SERVER) on 404page.php there is no mention of notexist url.

So how can i track my 404 pages.

Comment: Make sure you are not redirecting if a page cannot be found, but you are `including` the 404 page, so the URL remains the same, only the content has been changed to the 404 file.

Comment: In redirection there is no way to track it ?

Comment: You could try `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but no guarantee that it will work... The http referer can be spoofed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should use `ErrorDocument` with full path not relative:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /randomsite.com/404page.php
```

Then to get the actual URI for which you got 404 page you should use:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```